# How to separate dataframe columns as numerical, categorical and datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to split the columns of a dataframe by numerical, categorical, and datatime formats separately. I use `df.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64'])` and it works, but I'm not sure how to separate the **datatime** columns?

this is the dataset I have used

[image]

this is the command I have used to separate the date time column

date = df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime'])

The output I got

[image]

please help to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried something like this `converted_column = df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime'])` ?

Comment: I used this but I dint get the relevant output. i will update The details of Dataset I have used and the output I got in the question session. please help me on this.

Comment: So do you want both the `start date` and `end date` columns in the new dataframe?

Comment: yes exactly,  but without predefining the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below to separate the datetime columns however this only works if your column if of the datetime data type -

```
converted_column = df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime'])
```

If these columns are not in datetime type then we first need to convert and then extract them -

```
df['Start date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start date'])
df['End date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End date'])
```

[image: Example output]